# Check if List of Items exist in database and if not Add it to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

i want to check if List of items exist in database but if particular item does exist i want to insert it in database. Here is what i done but this code is hitting my database many times. Is there any way to do the same task with 1 or 2 hits.

```
foreach(var item in itemsList)
{
   if(!context.table.Find(x=> x.itemId == item))
   {
       table t= new table()
       {
         field1= 0,
         field2= 0
       }
       context.table.Add(s);
       context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fetch all existed item Ids, then create object for all non-existed items.
This way you do what you want with 2 hits:

```
var existedIds = context.table.Where(p => itemsList.Contains(p.itemId))
    .Select(p => p.itemId).ToList();

var nonExistedItems = itemsList.Except(existedIds)
    .Select(id => new Table
    {
        Id = id,
        field1 = 0,
        field2 = 0
    });

context.table.AddRange(nonExistedItems);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: can you help me out in one more thing? i want to extend a where clause such that whatever the parameter receive from  function it will filter the data based on that field value

Comment: for example: if Parameter is Name. then query look like .where(x=> x.name == parameterValue. if parameter is id query look like .where(x=> x.id == parameterValue). i can do this with if else if(searchBy == "Name") apply query for name if(searchBy == "store_id")  apply query for store_id but the problem is query is too much big .

Comment: @MuhammadSami It's better to ask another question. Anyway I think it's better to get `Filter Expression` as input parameter of your function like this: `Expression<Func<DataModel, bool>> filter`