# List of items relate to two tables one contain foreign key other the primary key and check if item contain primary key is not in the database insert

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have task to get list of items which contain properties related to two tables(Item, PurchaseItemOrder), This list contain the **Code** property related to **Item** class this property is not the primary key for business reasons. So I have to search in the database by this **Code** and if this **Item** does not exist in the database insert it, And finally return the **Id** of the **Item** which is the primary key and get this key as foreign key in another table **PurchaseItemOrder**, I did some code, and I see this question [Check if List of Items exist in database and if not Add it to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62309335/check-if-list-of-items-exist-in-database-and-if-not-add-it-to-database), but seems not exactly what I want can I do better?

Here May Code look like:

```
public class Item :Entity<int> , IFullAudited<User>
{
    public string Name_en { get; set; }
    public string Name_ar { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description_en { get; set; }
    public string Description_ar { get; set; }
    public User CreatorUser { get; set; }
    public User LastModifierUser { get; set; }
    public long? CreatorUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public long? LastModifierUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModificationTime { get; set; }
    public User DeleterUser { get; set; }
    public long? DeleterUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletionTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrderItem : Entity<int>, IFullAudited<User>
{
    public int POId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public User CreatorUser { get; set; }
    public User LastModifierUser { get; set; }
    public long? CreatorUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public long? LastModifierUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModificationTime { get; set; }
    public User DeleterUser { get; set; }
    public long? DeleterUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletionTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrderItemDto : EntityDto<int>
{
    public string PONumber { get; set; }

    public List<ItemDto> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDto :EntityDto<int>
{
    public string Name_en { get; set; }
    public string Name_ar { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description_en { get; set; }
    public string Description_ar { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}

private int CheckPO(PurchaseOrderItemDto dto)
    {
        var poExist = _purchaseOrderRepository.FirstOrDefault(po => po.PONumber == dto.PONumber);
        int id;

        if (poExist == null)
        {
            id = _purchaseOrderRepository.InsertAndGetId(new PurchaseOrder
            {
                PONumber = dto.PONumber,
                StatusId = 1
            });
        }

        else
        {
            id = poExist.Id;
        }

        return id;
    }

    private int CheckItem(ItemDto itemDto)
    {
        var itemExist = _itemRepository.FirstOrDefault(it => it.Code == itemDto.Code);
        int id;

        if (itemExist == null)
        {
            id = _itemRepository.InsertAndGetId(new Item
            {
                Name_en = itemDto.Name_en,
                Name_ar = itemDto.Name_en,
                Code = itemDto.Code,
                Description_en = itemDto.Description_en,
                Description_ar = itemDto.Description_ar
            });
        }

        else
        {
            id = itemExist.Id;
        }

        return id;
    }

    public void UploadPurchaseOrderItems(PurchaseOrderItemDto dto)
    {
        var poId = CheckPO(dto);

        foreach (var poItem in dto.Items)
        {
            int itemId = CheckItem(poItem);

            _repository.Insert(new PurchaseOrderItem
            {
                POId = poId,
                Qty = poItem.Qty,
                ItemId = itemId
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your `_itemRepository.InsertAndGetId`?You can try to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemDto););` to convert ItemDto to Item.

Comment: Ok, but this is not the main problem, are understand my actual problem?